# KineticsJS: any way to add a Line to an EXISTING layer?

Tags: kineticjs

I have the following code (using KineticJS HTML5 Canvas library):

```
    var dWidth = $(document).outerWidth() , dHeight = $(document).outerHeight();

    var window.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ // Kinetic stage = work area
        container: 'whole_page',
            width: dWidth,
        height: dHeight
    });

    // START
    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [{x:200,y:75},{x:656,y:171}],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
     });

    layer.add(line);

   // END

    stage.add(layer);
```

It works quite well, indeed the red line is drawn.

Let's suppose I want to add a **new** line to the **same** layer.
If I do it by adding the same code from // START to // END **after** stage.add(layer) no new line is drawn.
I also tried to draw lines **over a group**:

```
    var dWidth = $(document).outerWidth() , dHeight = $(document).outerHeight();

    var window.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ // Kinetic stage = work area
        container: 'whole_page',
            width: dWidth,
        height: dHeight
    });

    // START
    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [{x:200,y:75},{x:656,y:171}],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
     });

    group.add(line);
    layer.add(group);


   // END

    stage.add(layer);
```

but nothing changes.

How am I supposed to do it?
I have a page in which I need to add new lines **dynamically** (according to user interaction), thus the only solution that comes to my mind is have **a layer per each line** but it's quite tricky and inefficient.

Also: is there any way to REDRAW "from scratch" (that is, **delete the line, redraw it from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)**) a line I **already added**?

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic function that takes in [x1,y1,x2,y2] and creates a new line.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LYF23/

```
function addLine(points){
    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points:points,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
    layer.add(line);

    // don't forget to do layer.draw after creating the line or it won't appear
    layer.draw();
    return(line);
}
```

And you can call the function to add a line like this:

```
var lineNumberOne = addLine([25,50,100,20]);
```

And you can remove that line like this:

```
lineNumberOne.destroy();
layer.draw();
```

Remember to call layer.draw() while creating or destroying shapes so your changes appear on the layer.

You can change the x's and y's that make up a line using .setPoints.  This is much more efficient than destroying the line and creating a new line with new points.

```
lineNumberOne.setPoints([50,150,200,25]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this way I have no control on the single lines (let's suppose for example I want to delete some line at a certain point). Right?

Comment: Check my revised answer that shows a generic function for adding, changing and deleting new lines to a layer.